# Bash не работает sed на замену переменной

Tags: bash, replace

Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно заменить значение в переменной файла. Условно пусть есть перменная uno=1 dos=2. В тексте нужно заменить uno на dos.
При использовании команды sed по принципу замены текста

```
echo "This is 1 This is 2" | sed 's%1%2%g'
```

команда работает

При попытке выполнения

```
echo " This is $uno This is $dos"
```

вывод работает, т.е. переменные определены, но при попытке замены с помощью sed - замена не производится.
Для sed использовалась команда:

```
echo "This is $uno This is $dos" | sed 's%$(uno)%$(dos)'
```

Теоретически такая команда должна вывести текст  "This is 2 This is 2", но выводится обычный текст. В чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: Переменные в одинарных кавычках не интерполируются.

Comment: `echo "This is $uno This is $dos" | sed "s%${uno}%${dos}%"` - попробуйте так

Comment: И каким образом их интерполировать? Обратный слеш их не экранирует, подобные способы из других языков и сред тоже.  Только исключать из кавычек?

Comment: Используйте двойные кавычки

Comment: Вы же не в echo передаёте созданный sed текст, а просто он выводит его. Вам надо же в echo передать результат sed, чтобы произошла замена.

Comment: Ipatev_nn, ваш пример работает, благодарю. Получается двойные кавычки везде нужны, я правильно понял?

Comment: Вообще попахивает X-Y проблемой

Comment: У вас команда sed не была завершена, в конце отсутствовал разделитель`%` и что бы подставить значение переменной, устанавливайте двойные кавычки, все верно

Comment: На будущее. `set -x`, затем вводите свои команды. это отладочный режим. многие вещи в нем будут более понятны.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки в команде:

```
... | sed 's%$(uno)%$(dos)%'
# отсутствует разделитель_^
```

Используется одинарные кавычки. Например, отличие одинарных кавычек от двойных:

```
var='str'
echo '$var'
>>> $var
echo "$var"
>>> str
```

Неверный вызов переменных:

```
var='ls'
echo "$(var)"
#______^___^ использование круглых скобок предназначено для вызова программ и команд
>>> var: команда не найдена
echo "$var"
>>> ls
echo "${var}"
>>> ls
```

---

Использование фигурных скобок зачастую помогает в ограничении имени переменной, к примеру, у нас есть 3 каталога - masterdir, slavedir, otherdir. В результате работы некоего скрипта мы получаем значение - master, slave или other соответственно. И что бы правильно получить имя каталога, к переменной нужно присоединить текст dir

```
var='master'
echo "/path/$vardir"
>>> /path/
#Так как переменной $vardir не объявлено, то и вывод будет пустой
echo "/path/${var}dir"
>>> /path/masterdir
```